# Moving a block of code by a tabspace

Tags: vim, vi

I am currently visually selecting the code and typing ">" which moves the code by 2 tabs. But I only want to move it by one tab.

Is there any alternate command in VIM to move the code by a tabspace.
Ideally I would like to put a marker and then move the whole code block by a tabspace.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will set your shifting width to four spaces (default tab size):

```
:set sw=4
```

You can also change the size of the tab stop itself (X is any value you like):

```
:set ts=X
```

And if you like to use spaces instead of tab characters, use this:

```
:set expandtab
```

If you use the same settings in many files, you can put these in your `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>></kbd> moves the code by one [shiftwidth](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27shiftwidth%27). So you need to set that option correctly.

Comment: But which option?  Not as helpful an answer as the one by Marcin.

Comment: The option "shiftwidth" (or "sw" for short). Just follow the link to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

There are easier ways to do what you want, as others have pointed out, but the
following is of more general use:

- You can select a column by pressing **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>** and then using the **<kbd>up</kbd>** and **<kbd>down</kbd>** keys (or **<kbd>j</kbd>** and **<kbd>k</kbd>**).
- Next press **<kbd>I</kbd>** to go to insert mode. Now you can type anthing you like. In your case, type a single **<kbd>tab</kbd>**.
- Finish by pressing **<kbd>esc</kbd>**, and see how your edit is applied to all lines.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'd regard that as easier than using the shift operators for shifting text, but it is interesting to see what the visual block does - so +1 for that.